# How to make text float on top of an image html css

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-float, css-position

I have the following html code to make the 'bottom' div float on top of the image. I have 3 images on one table row.

```
<td>
     <img src="adele.jpg" alt="Adele">
     <div id="bottom">
        <h4 class="topText">ALBUM</h4>
        <h3 class ="topText">ADELE 21 COVER </br> ADELE</h3>
    </div>
</td>
```

this is my css:

```
#bottom{
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  bottom: 0px;
  left:0px;

}

#positionAnchor {
   position: relative;
}
```

also as you can see in the image, the top pictures text is also not floating on top of the image properly.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use position:relative to set window where position:absolute will use for top, left, bottom, and right.

```
<td >
     <div id="positionAnchor">
     <img src="adele.jpg" alt="Adele">
     <div id="bottom">
        <h4 class="topText">ALBUM</h4>
        <h3 class ="topText">ADELE 21 COVER </br> ADELE</h3>
    </div>
    </div>
</td>

#bottom{
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
#positionAnchor {
 position: relative;
 display: inline-block;
 text-align:center;
}
```

Otherwise it will position based on the browser screen not the parent tag.

Comment: I tried this, but It still doesn't work, you can see the change in picture above.

Comment: Add left: 0px to the CSS, see update. Without specifying the left position it is defaulting to its current left position. or place the id=bottom element before the img tag, so it will begin at the far left and layer itself onto the image.

Comment: Sorry the image did not make sence when I posted the answer.

Comment: hi, thank you for your answer. This solution works when the screen is half the size, however when it is full screen then it doesn't work. I have added a new image now.

Comment: Updated my answer, the styling for the td must be centering the contents and so we need a wrapper which is centered with the image to anchor to.

Comment: and we need to have the width of the div expand to the width of the image unless that is fixed. div tags by default expand so setting its width to 1 if it is not known will work, but it is better to use the actual width. without a width setting div take 100% width which also does not work.

Comment: see update, are the images fixed width, the image width is what should be used.

Comment: You do have <!DOCTYPE html> so the browser is not in quirks mode?

Comment: the width:1px; did the job :)

Comment: I have, I seem to have a further problem, which I think is caused by the width:1px; 

the problem i have added on here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25961410/alighinig-table-rows-and-columns

Comment: Replace width:1px; with text-align:center; then.

Comment: see update also use inline block so it will not expand to 100%

Answer (score 0):

Use this css

```
        #bottom{
          position: relative;
          margin-top: -60%;
        }
```

Adjust the margin according to your needs.

Comment: Thanx for the answer. The only problem with this is that the image at the very top is still disalighned with the text.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than use position absolute to get img overlapping with a div, I would recommend using the background-image property on the div instead. Then all you would need to do is adjust the text to be centered within the div.

Answer (score 0):

When you create your objects, think about it in layers. (Top layer loads last.)

If you create two position:absolute containers for the text and images, you can "float" the text above the image.

```css
.LogoWrapper{
 position:absolute;
 left:5px;
 top:3px;
 background-image:url("http://www.delaneysecurity.com/Images/Background/bg.png");
 width:275px;
 }

.LogoWord{
 font-size:30px;
 font-weight:bold;
 color:#F0F0F0;
 font-family: arial;
 position:absolute;
 left:20px;
 top:25px;
 }
```

```html
<HTML>
  <BODY>
    <DIV CLASS="LogoWrapper">
  <IMG SRC="http://www.delaneysecurity.com/Images/Images/logocircles.png"/>
    </DIV>
    <DIV CLASS="LogoWord">Delaney Security</DIV>
  </BODY>
</HTML>
```